# KeyError: 'sites' when using JSON in Python

Tags: python, json, flask

I'm getting a KeyError while using the JSON library in Python (with Flask)
I don't really understand it.

```
KeyError: 'sites'
```

is the error I'm getting

JSON Code:

```
{
  "sites": {
      "example-site": {
          "domains": [
              "example.pagehost.com",
              "127.0.0.1:5000"
          ],
          "pages": {
              "index/": "index.html"
          },
          "index": "index.html",
          "owner": "Bevan",
          "id": "example-site"
      }
   }
}
```

Python Code:

```
global sites_json
fsite = ""
print("Finding site")
for site in sites_json['sites']:
    for domain in site['domains']:
        if domain == host:
            fsite = site
            print("Found site")
            break
```

The infringing line appears to be the **for site in sites_json['sites']**
May someone who knows what is going on please help?

Comment: Please show the type of `sites_json`: `print(type(sites_json))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some messing around, it turns out that I was launching my Flask app through the **python3 -m flask run** command, which skipped my JSON file's initialisation steps. When I launch through the **python3 app.py** command, it works correctly!